# Devexpress XtraReports Script editor Crashes when pressing two consequent single quotes

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress, xtrareport

I am using DevExpress XtraReport for a reporting software.I faced a weird problem with the script editor. Using the script editor, Whenever I press the single quotation button on my key board (') consequently two times, the visual studio is crashed each time with exeption.

The error message is

```
Message: Unhandled Exception was thrown.
Type: DevExpress.CodeRush.Common.DXCoreUnhandledException
Source: 
Target Site: 

Call Stack:
at System.String.CtorCharCount(Char c, Int32 count)
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.AddCommentNode(Token lCommentToken, FormattingParsingElement lastElement)
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.Get()
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.FieldDecl(TypeReferenceExpression typeRef, AccessSpecifiers accessSpecifiers, MemberVisibility visibility, LanguageElementCollection attributes)
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.LocalVariableDeclaration()
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.Statement()
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.StatementSeq()
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.BlockCore(Boolean isMethodBlock)
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.MethodDeclaration(TypeReferenceExpression typeRef, ElementReferenceExpression memberName, AccessSpecifiers accessSpecifiers, MemberVisibility visibility, LanguageElementCollection attributes)
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.StructMemberDeclaration(AccessSpecifiers accessSpecifiers, MemberVisibility visibility, LanguageElementCollection attributes)
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.ClassMemberDeclaration(AccessSpecifiers accessSpecifiers, MemberVisibility visibility, LanguageElementCollection attributes)
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.ClassMemberSeq()
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.NamespaceMemberDeclaration()
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.Parser()
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.Parse()
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharp30Parser.Parse(ISourceReader reader)
at DevExpress.CodeParser.CSharp.CSharpTokensHelper.GetTokens(String code)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.SyntaxHighlightService.GetTokens()
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.SyntaxHighlightService.Execute()
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.DocumentModel.PerformSyntaxHighlight(Boolean forced)
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.DocumentModel.OnLastEndUpdateCore()
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Model.DocumentModel.DevExpress.Utils.IBatchUpdateHandler.OnLastEndUpdate()
at DevExpress.Utils.BatchUpdateHelper.EndUpdate()
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands.RichEditSelectionCommand.ExecuteCore()
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands.RichEditMenuItemSimpleCommand.ForceExecute(ICommandUIState state)
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands.MultiCommand.ExecuteCommand(Command command, ICommandUIState state)
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands.MultiCommand.ForceExecuteCore(ICommandUIState state)
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands.MultiCommand.ForceExecute(ICommandUIState state)
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands.TransactedMultiCommand.ForceExecute(ICommandUIState state)
at DevExpress.Utils.Commands.Command.Execute()
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Keyboard.NormalKeyboardHandler.FlushPendingTextInputCore(String pendingInput)
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Keyboard.NormalKeyboardHandler.PerformFlushPendingTextInput(String pendingInput)
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Keyboard.NormalKeyboardHandler.FlushPendingTextInput()
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Internal.InnerRichEditControl.FlushPendingTextInput()
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.OnFlushPendingTextInputTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Drawing.LeakSafeEventRouter.OnFlushPendingTextInputTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


OS Version: Win32NT, 6.1.7600.0
VS Version: 10.0, Professional
DXCore Version: 11.1.4.0
0 installed add-ins:
```

The snapshot of the crashed window is also attached :[image]

If anybody could explain the reason of the crash then it will be a great deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is caused by CodeRush.  Try disabling CodeRush to see if the issue still arises.

The fact it happens when typing '' suggests that CodeRush is trying to process a template and failing.

You could try repairing your CodeRush installation or disabling the '' template within the CodeRush settings.